# What's the best way to define a scope inside of a module in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a number of models that need the same scope. They each have an `expiration_date` date field that I want to write a scope against.

To keep things DRY, I'd like to put the scope in a module (in /lib) that I'll extend each model with. However, when I call `scope` within the module, the method is undefined.

To work around this, I use `class_eval` when the module is included:

```
module ExpiresWithinScope
  def self.extended(base)
    scope_code = %q{scope :expires_within, lambda { |number_of_months_from_now| where("expiration_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", Date.today, Date.today + number_of_months_from_now) } }
    base.class_eval(scope_code)
  end 
end
```

I then do `extend ExpiresWithinScope` in my models.

This approach works, but feels a little hackish. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With AR3, they finally got somewhere near DataMapper awesomeness, so you can go

```
module ExpiresWithinScope
  def expires_within(months_from_now)
    where("expiration_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", 
    Date.today,
    Date.today + number_of_months_from_now) 
  end
end
```

You could also try:

```
module ExpiresWithinScope
  def expires_within(months_from_now)
    where(:expiration_date => Date.today..(Date.today + number_of_months_from_now))
  end
end
```

But according to [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions), arel can't handle that as well.

Answer (score 10):

You could do something a little cleaner like this, since scope is a public class method:

```
module ExpiresWithinScope
  def self.included(base)
    base.scope :expires_within, lambda { |number_of_months_from_now| 
      base.where("expiration_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", 
        Date.today,
        Date.today + number_of_months_from_now) 
    }
  end 
end
```

and then in your model

```
include ExpiresWithinScope
```

Comment: ah, lexical scoping strikes again.